# Use HTML,CSS and Javascript in java code using IDE Eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, eclipse

I am new to java and stuck in trying to embed the HTML/CSS and Javascript to the java code. 
Any pointers will be helpful to finish building my code. I am using Eclipse editor to write my java code.

I have been able to successfully display some part of HTML display in my java code as below however I am trying to achieve a table sort via html/css/javascript and would like to add  that too to my java code.

Below is my display.java file

```
          public void transformForRequestSuccessful(MarkupOutput out) {
           //Call render methods
        renderdisplay(out);
                       }
     public void renderdisplay(MarkupOutput out) 
            {
            out.append("<BR/>");
            out.append("<p>Look at the body!</p>");

            out.append("<BR/>");
             }
```

Below is the HTML/CSS/JavaScript that can be pasted as is and runs fine.

I saved this HTML file as sort.html and when called independently works fine.

```
html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
        var rows = tbody.rows,
            rlen = rows.length,
            arr = new Array(),
            i, j, cells, clen;
        // fill the array with values from the table
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].cells;
            clen = cells.length;
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order 
     (asc)
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * 
     asc);
        });
        // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
        }
    }
     </script>
     <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: none;
    }
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 4px 16px;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #C8C8C8;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
   </head>

  <body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; 
   asc3 = 1;">ServerName</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; 
   asc1 = 1;">UserName</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc1 = 1; 
   asc2 = 1;">JobId</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="people">
        <tr>
            <td>Server1</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Server2</td>
            <td>XYZ</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Any help or suggestions how to embed this in java code will be helpful.
My apologies if I sound naive or unaware of the basic java programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to escape the special characters you need to integrate the OWASP encoder to encode the data for JS or CSS. Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/wiki/2)-Use-the-OWASP-Java-Encoder)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following frameworks:

- Spring IO: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

This example shows you how to create the server and store your HTML/CSS/JavaScript. On the other hand, create a REST service to create a response with your embed HTML code.

- JQuery: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/

This example shows you how to consume a RESTful Web Service with jQuery and append the embed code

Answer (score 0):

Although it will not work alone but hope this will help you out to understand the implementation. This is a sample JSP file. In JSP file you can embed java code in the form of tags (scriplet,declarative and expression).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="com.demo.dto.RegisterDTO"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.model.Student"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootsrtap Free Admin Template - SIMINTA | Admin Dashboad Template</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-big-counter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="assets/css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Page-Level CSS -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <%List<RegisterDTO> entity = (List<RegisterDTO>)(request.getAttribute("entity")); %>

</head>

<body>
    <!--  wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- navbar top -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
            <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- end navbar-header -->
            <!-- navbar-top-links -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <!-- main dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-danger">3</span><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown-messages -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-danger">Andrew Smith</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-info">Jonney Depp</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong><span class=" label label-success">Jonney Depp</span></strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-messages -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-success">4</span>  <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown tasks -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <span class="top-label label label-warning">5</span>  <i class="fa fa-bell fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown alerts-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i>New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i>3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i>Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- dropdown user-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i>Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- end main dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- end navbar-top-links -->

        </nav>
        <!-- end navbar top -->

        <!-- navbar side -->
        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <!-- sidebar-collapse -->
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <!-- side-menu -->
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <!-- user image section-->
                        <div class="user-section">
                            <div class="user-section-inner">
                                <img src="assets/img/user.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="user-info">
                                <div>Jonny <strong>Deen</strong></div>
                                <div class="user-text-online">
                                    <span class="user-circle-online btn btn-success btn-circle "></span>&nbsp;Online
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end user image section-->
                    </li>
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <!-- search section-->
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!--end search section-->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="User.jsp"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>Manage Users</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Morris Charts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-flask fa-fw"></i>Timeline</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i>Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- third-level-items -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i>Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- second-level-items -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end side-menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- end sidebar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <!-- end navbar side -->
        <!--  page-wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">


            <div class="row">
                 <!--  page header -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Tables</h1>
                </div>
                 <!-- end  page header -->
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <form method="post" action="MyServlet">
            <input type="hidden" value=1 name="userAction"/>
            <input type="submit" name="showData" value="showData"/>
            </form>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <!--   Kitchen Sink -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            User Details
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>First Name</th>
                                            <th>Last Name</th>
                                            <th>Contact</th>
                                             <th>Email</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <% if(entity != null){
                                    for(RegisterDTO data:entity){ %>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><%=data.getId() %></td>
                                             <td><%=data.getFirstName() %></td>
                                              <td><%=data.getLastName() %></td>
                                               <td><%=data.getContact() %></td>
                                                <td><%=data.getEmail() %></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <% }
                                        }%>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <!-- End  Kitchen Sink -->
                </div>

            </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->

    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/siminta.js"></script>
    <!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In this, I also made a dynamic table using scriplet tag.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am using asp.net. Can you please post sample example for ASP?

Comment: But you ask for java code. how could you embed java code in asp.net? Please clarify your question

Comment: What I meant was i am using IIS as my web server. What i am trying to achieve is similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842683/string-builder-into-html-table-format but i am unable to esc the special chars used in my css and js. So need help around that.

Comment: For e,g hot to use.append for this line <style type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

If you're new, you're going to be exposed to many different approaches to accomplishing the same thing - how to get your Java code to work with other web technologies. IMO, Spring Boot is one of the quickest ways to get started, as @pakOverflow mentions above.

Another great (and simple)  intro is from MyKong: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

One (of the many) thing to keep in mind is that you want to separate concerns (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In Java, strive to have fairly small, simple objects work together to do interesting things rather than putting all your code in a very small number of classes that do everything.